# Pyspark Dataframes: Creating a features column to be used in the clustering in python

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm trying to create implement k-means clustering in pyspark. I am using the mnist as my dataset, which has hundreds of columns with integer values.

After creating a data-frame, when I try to create a features column to be used in the clustering, I don't know what to give as a `inputCols` parameter for `VectorAssembler`. Below is my code

```
sc = SparkContext('local')
spark = SparkSession(sc)

df = spark.read.csv('mnist_train.csv')
df.show()
df_feat = df.select(*(df[c].cast("float").alias(c) for c in df.columns[0:]))
df_feat.show()

vecAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = ???????, outputCol = "features")
```

What should I put as parameter for `inputCols` for this large integer valued data that I am using?

Answer (score 0):

The [Vectorassembler](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler) needs a list of column names to create a feature vector. So for the mnist dataset you could give him everything except of the labels. For example:

```
#I assume that df_feat.columns[0] is the column which contains the labels
cols = df_feat.columns[1:]
vecAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = cols, outputCol = "features")
```